# Why double inject an Android Application in Dagger?

Tags: dagger-2, android-architecture-components, dagger

Looking at the source code for the Android Architecture Components sample [GithubBrowerSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample), I don't understand the point of double injecting the `githubApp`.

Wouldn't the `inject` method be enough? Why do it need both of them in the same sentence?

```
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(GithubApp githubApp);
}
```

And they use it like:

```
public static void init(GithubApp githubApp) {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(githubApp)
                .build().inject(githubApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Thomas Broyer described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090287/1426891), you've got two separate directions to set up: You want the Dagger graph to know how to get to your Application instance, and you want to get access to certain bindings out of the dependency graph.

The `@BindsInstance` line in the Builder creates a binding for Application set to the instance you pass in. It sounds like you understand this part.

However, after you've created your Component, presumably you want to *use* it. Let's say you want to get fully-injected instances of classes Dep1, Dep2, and Dep3 out of your graph. One way you could do this is to create methods on your Component that get the instances:

```
@Singleton @Component(/* ... */) interface AppComponent {
    // [builder snipped out here]

    fun getDep1(): Dep1
    fun getDep2(): Dep2
    fun getDep3(): Dep3
}
```

And then you call those as part of your App creation.

```
var appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(githubApp).build()
var dep1 = appComponent.getDep1()
var dep2 = appComponent.getDep2()
var dep3 = appComponent.getDep3()
// Use dep1, dep2, and dep3 here.
```

However, you can also create a single-arg method, which is typically a `void` method called `inject`. This populates all of the `@Inject`-annotated fields and calls all of the `@Inject`-annotated methods on the instance you pass in. If GitHubApp has `@Inject`-annotated-fields ([and it does](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/GithubApp.kt#L28-L30)), the call to `inject` lets you skip defining all of the getters on the Component. That reduces all of the above code to:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(githubApp)
    .build().inject(githubApp)
```

...which is what you see in the demo.

Comment: Ohhhh I see, I thought the builder would take care of all of the @Inject instances, even the ones in the object provided to the builder

Comment: @mFeinstein Right. `@BindsInstance` doesn't have any side effects and doesn't inject anything, it _just_ instructs Dagger which instance to provide for a certain binding later on. In this specific case, it _just_ says to inject the GitHubApp instance for any Application bindings.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, you are the best!

Answer (score 2):

The `@BindsInstance` tells Dagger that it should inject the application into whichever `@Inject Application` it finds in the dependency graph.

The second asks Dagger to inject dependencies into it's `@Inject`-annotated fields and methods. This the root of the dependency graph.

Technically, the component method can be called as many times as you like, while the builder method can only be called once.

Comment: I understand the first case `@BindsInstance`, but I don't understand the second case... What's the difference between them? They sound as the same for me, maybe I don't understand the inner workings of Dagger?

Comment: Dagger needs to look for all the `@Inject`-annotated members of some root objects to derive a dependency graph. It will then generate the appropriate code to fullfil those dependencies. The `@BindsInstance` is kinda the reverse: it's an opaque object, completely independent from the dependency graph but that needs to be injected into it as a dependency to some of the objects (a leaf in the graph). The code you're showing here does not require that you pass the same object to both methods, it is your use case that requires it. Dagger is not Android-specific, it only provides helpers for Android